# Process installation with Progressbar not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, backgroundworker

I know i put process in for loop that not the correct way , I just want to know how can i update progress bar with installation, Progress bar update accordingly the process installation. And when installation begin progress bar updated in my case after installation running in background.

```
void _bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void _bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.textblock1.Text = "Completed";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.textblock1.Text = ("Error :" + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                progressbar1.Maximum = 100;
                progressbar1.Minimum = 1;
                progressbar1.Value = progressbar1.Maximum;
                textblock1.Text = "Completed";
            }

        }

  private readonly BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public ControlPanelFinal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SilverLightInstall();
            _bw.DoWork += _bw_DoWork;
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += _bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            _bw.ProgressChanged += _bw_ProgressChanged;
            _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
       }

                string filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Silverlight.exe");
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /q  /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", filepath);
                p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                p.Start();
```

}

Comment: Your installation is in the Silverlight process that you spawn?

Comment: You can't. Since you have no idea what is the _precise_ percentage of the installation progress, you can't report that percentage to update progressbar. A workaround would be report 30%, then do the actual installation, and then report 100% after install process exit with 0.

Comment: @MickyDuncan yes silverlight process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can even do this will depend on what your Silverlight process is actually doing and whether it itself provides any notifications of progress, such as by writing to stdout or offering some inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism for the purpose.

For example, if the process does write to stdout, you might do something like this:

```
void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    string filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Silverlight.exe");
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /q  /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", filepath);
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();

    string line;

    while ((line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(ConvertStdoutToProgress(line));
    }
}
```

where the `ConvertStdoutToProgress()` method is some hypothetical method you'd write that can interpret a line of output from the process and translate that to some percentage progress value.

*(Note: redirecting stdout so you can read it requires setting `UseShellExecute` to `false`, but this might interfere with your scenario. I see you are setting the `Verb` property, which I'm not sure could be used without `UseShellExecute` set to `true`. If not, then obviously you could not use stdout redirection for progress. But you may not be able to anyway…the above is really just an example to illustrate the basic technique; you'd have to customize it to your specific case anyway).*

If you do not have a way of reliably retrieving progress information from the process, then the best approach is to not try to indicate real progress at all. You can still use the `ProgressBar`, but set the `Style` property to `ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`. This will cause the `ProgressBar` to display an animated indication of activity (the exact indication varies according to platform, but this is usually a filled bar with an animated highlight that moves across it periodically).

You *could* set up a loop with a timer *after* starting the process, that fakes the progress up to a point (you wouldn't want to show a full completion, but maybe up to 80-90%), completing early if the process itself completes early, and simply waiting at the near-full completion state if the timed loop completes before the process. But I wouldn't advise it. I personally find this sort of progress indication annoying, because it implies presentation of information that doesn't really exist.

Comment: @Dhru'soni: Like I wrote: that method is "some hypothetical method you'd write". I.e. it's up to you to _implement_ that method. You're the only one who knows what the output of your process is and how to interpret it, so you're the only person who can write that method.